# Can power to weight ratio be used to calculate theoretical 0-60 times?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, kinematics, acceleration, torque

The power to weight ratio is used to calculate how fast a car can accelerate. If a car has 400 hp and a weight of 2000 lbs (400/2000), it should make 0.2 hp per pound. If I switch the fraction around (2000/400), does this mean that its theoretical 0-60 time is 5 seconds? I don't know if this will always be the case so that's why I'm asking because I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why you see such a direct relationship between power, mass and time. You might like to look at the units (or more strictly Dimensions) to see that power/mass does not give any indication of time.

I assume you mean the car has a MASS of 2000 lbs.

A car does not normally develop constant power - you are probably quoting the MAXIMUM power, but we will assume that the car develops 400HP constant...

Power is 'rate of doing work' and 1 HP = 550 ft lbf /s
=550 x32 lb ft/s^3
And work done = Power *time = 400 x 550 x 32 x Time

Your car has a mass of 2000lbs and you are looking at a final velocity of 60mph =88 fps

So the KE of the car is 0.5 mv^2 = 1000 lbs * 88^2 ft^2/s^2

Total work done by engine = KE of car (in 'ideal' theoretical conditions)

So time = (1000 x 88^2) / (400 x 550 x 32)
= 1.1 s

The reason why this is unreal is as stated - the car does not develop maximum power from t=0.
Without knowing the relationship between power and time you cannot get a realistic estimate..

Answer (score 0):

A bit too late to the party but I hope it helps (at least future readers).

Convert the units; HP to Watts and pounds to kilograms.

Power to weight -> W/kg is equivalent to mˆ2 / sˆ3, effectively speed * acceleration.

For a given vehicle speed in m/s at a known gear ratio, you can calculate the maximum engine power in Watts. The power [W] can be divided by the vehicle weight (dry weight + fuel + passengers + cargo) [kg] and the speed [m/s] to find the maximum acceleration [m/sˆ2].